# Is SWFUpload still alive?

Tags: flash, file-upload, swfupload

I'm considering using SWFUpload on my site, but I saw that the last release was in March 2010, and it was a beta. It looks like the SWFUpload people stopped there development.

Is this project still alive? Is there an alternative?

Comment: I'm wondering why there's an asp.net tag in a question that seems to have nothing to do with ASP.

Comment: Because I wanted the ASP.NET developers to answer since my site is in ASP.NET and there are many projects / samples of file upload without ASP.NET example

Comment: I don't believe that's how tags are supposed to be used (Seems spammy).   Your question has nothing to do with ASP so this tag is irrelevant.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, **SWFUpload** looks pretty dead...

No Issue updates since June 2010 at Google Code...

http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/issues/list

There ***IS* lots of recent activity** at the official SWFUpload discussion forum.  Have you asked there yet?

http://groups.google.com/group/swfupload/topics

As far as alternatives, there's quite a few...

http://www.solmetra.com/en/disp.php/en_products/flash_uploader/uploader_intro

http://www.uploadify.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx

---

**EDIT:**

http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/

This article contains a few already rejected outright by OP, but the others are worth looking...

http://www.cult-f.net/multiple-file-uploaders/

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

http://clubajax.org/the-new-dojo-html5-multi-file-uploader/

---

**EDIT 2:**

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

http://www.freshdesignweb.com/10example-ajax-upload-file-with-php.html

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/file

Comment: Well, no reason to ask if there is no one to answer... As far as Uploadify, the developer said that he will no continue to develop this because his lack of time. Solmetras' upload isnt support multifile selection and there is no sign of the date. Since I'm searching for project that is alive codeproject - FlashUpload isnt really an option..

Comment: You might try http://www.plupload.com/ , it's active (at least in comparison to these other apps) and supports flash uploads as well as HTML5.

Comment: @nir: I said, "there IS lots of recent activity..."  Not sure why you think us at StackOverflow would know more about the current status of SWFUpload than anyone already at the SWFUpload forum.  Typically if there's activity, there are also people there who've been in touch with the Developers.  It never hurts to ask.  As far as my other suggestions, perhaps including which solutions you've already tried within your original question would have been helpful in obtaining a desired answer.  Before I go through the effort of posting more links, I'll ask if you're open to a jQuery solution?

Comment: I said so because I already popped a question there and there was no answer. Yes I'm open to JQuery, many of your links looks good. I'll look deeper in the next days and choose one. When I just start to look for image upload I looked for an javascript + asp.net only without any flash/silverlight etc.. with multifile selection and that it will support most used browsers (IE6+,FF3+,chrome). But I didnt find such a tool(that was free anyway).

Comment: @nir:  **you wrote:**  _"I said so because I already popped a question there and there was no answer."_  While previously you said, _"no reason to ask..."_.  Either you did or you didn't... why is a clear response so hard?  As far as free... yes, I believe you should be able to find something good in one of the links I posted.

Comment: =] if you read well you see the difference I wrote that I popped a question, and in the other post I said there is no reason to ask(that question).. I asked there a question about a problem that I have with swfupload and there was no response. Therefor I didnt saw any reason to post another question, and instead I wrote my question here. As far as my request I'll need to review [ajax-upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) and [multiple-file-upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload) deeply, maybe with some customizations one of them will fit for me. if not then flash plugin

Comment: I can read just fine and your vagueness is not helpful to anyone.  I'll repeat my original suggestion... if you actually posted a topic there titled, "Is this project dead?" you may draw a few interesting or helpful responses.

Comment: Well I'm sorry it came out that way, there is no reason for me to be vague. Anyway I'll post there my question.

Comment: Yes, if anyone that's even slightly informed/involved with SWFUpload is browsing the Google group, a thread title like the one I suggested should certainly catch their attention.  If not, then the first part of your Stackoverflow question will be self-evident.

Comment: BTW: Keep away from "Uploadify", even if its price is low, it is no more than a fork of SWFUpload, sexed up with nice API. But it is mostly unmaintained, just as SWFUpload itself. :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working in ASP.NET you might consider Telerik. They have an uploader and a whole lot more for making a site look and work pretty good.